# Can't install Oracle JDK 9

Tags: apt, jdk

I uninstalled jdk packages and now can't install them back. I managed to install oracle-java7-installer and oracle-java8-installer but can't install oracle-java9-installer. It seems that my computer tries to download wrong version of oracle-java9-installer 177 when version i would be able to download is 178.

```
$ wget http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/178/binaries/jdk-9+178_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
--2017-07-21 11:00:02--  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/178/binaries/jdk-9+178_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Connecting to 10.144.1.10:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 293348142 (280M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: 'jdk-9+178_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz'

jdk-9+178_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz     1%[>                                                          ]   5.42M  5.04MB/s               ^C

$ wget http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/177/binaries/jdk-9+177_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
--2017-07-21 11:00:16--  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/177/binaries/jdk-9+177_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Connecting to 10.144.1.10:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-21 11:00:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Can you help? `apt-get` tries to install Oracle JDK 9.

I run Ubuntu 16.04 in virtual machine hosted by win7

Full error message:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java9-installer is already the newest version (9b177-1~webupd8~0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up oracle-java9-installer (9b177-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 9...
--2017-07-21 10:54:11--  http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/177/binaries/jdk-9+177_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Connecting to 10.144.1.10:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-21 10:54:13 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java9-installerE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Check your network connection on your VM.

Comment: Definitely not a network issue. The file doesn't exist.

Comment: Just tried to install from the `webupd8` PPA and it was successful without having to modify any of the files mentioned in previous answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the GA release version of the JDK use:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="2ef49c97ddcd5e0de20226eea4cca7b0d7de63ddec80eff8291513f6474ca0dc"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1c6d783a54fcc0673ed1f8c5e8650b1d8977ca3e856a03fba0090198e0f16f6d"|' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=181|JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=181|' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|FILENAME=jdk-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}+${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}_linux-${dld}_bin.tar.gz|FILENAME=jdk-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}_linux-${dld}_bin.tar.gz|' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.java.net/java/jdk${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}/archive/${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}/binaries/$FILENAME|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}+${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}/$FILENAME|' oracle-java9-installer.*
```

Comment: Nice! Works awesome!

Comment: Maybe you should share your solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/958241/java-9-official-release-how-to-install-jdk9-directly?noredirect=1&lq=1 as well.

Comment: Not working as of now (result is: `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9+181/jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1520554549_5bf6956d13a5d1a36d40ce55d3ccf989
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.21.188.165|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found`)

Answer (score 10):

I've just experienced the same problem and done the following:

1. `cd  /var/lib/dpkg/info/`
2. in all files `oracle-java9-installer.*` change version numbers 177->178 and SHA256SUM_TGZ to what you see on the official website
3. `sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer`

I know that it is dirty and incorrect way, but I didn't manage to find any alternatives

Comment: "and SHA256SUM_TGZ to what you see on the official website"  Could you provide said value, or website's url ?  I feel like I'm looking for a needle in a haystack

Comment: I found the SHAs here: http://jdk.java.net/9/ (accept the terms first). I'm working through Olga's solution to see if it works now...

Comment: Confirmed that it works!  Make sure you get the SHA256 from the correct Linux type (ARM vs not; 32 vs 64).  You don't need to replace ALL of the SHA256 hashes -- only the one for the architecture your computer uses.

Comment: Thanks alot! you saved me from creating new VM which would have took for like 1-2 working days!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/966163/46543 answer works now (2017-10-18).

Answer (score 10):

Prefer a friend solution

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's/=177/=179/' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's/SHA256SUM_TGZ="a6905f3a4245a071880e1793b8d3d6100ef7b171ea1d6ebfe6312c25c2fca8bb"/SHA256SUM_TGZ="06fe58dfa50c4f6ca21dc1d475f16cd9e58db36b1d98582091d7ff9005dda7a7"/' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

Comment: This is the most precise of all the answers.  It actually gives you the direct commands to fix the issue.

Comment: This no longer works. The URL is now different:
Was: http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/archive/181/binaries/jdk-9+181_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Is: http://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk9/9/binaries/jdk-9+181_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Comment: @ST-DDT none of both links worked for me now. I used this one: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz but you need to accept license agreement first.

Answer (score 8):

The newest version of the installer, 9.0.1-1~webupd8~0, now functions properly.

Previous answers do not work for version 9b181-1~webupd8~2 of the installer, and some previous versions.

Note, the JDK version is 9.0.1 now, not 9 (beta) as this installer expected. It was out of date, downloads had been (re)moved also, so it couldn't even get the old beta to install.

The following worked:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

You can use `ls oracle-java9*` to see relevant files in this directory:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

Fix the incorrect sum, in `oracle-java9-installer.config` actually:

```
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="2ef49c97ddcd5e0de20226eea4cca7b0d7de63ddec80eff8291513f6474ca0dc"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="2cdaf0ff92d0829b510edd883a4ac8322c02f2fc1beae95d048b6716076bc014"|' oracle-java9-installer.*
```

Fix a second incorrect sum, in `oracle-java9-installer.postinst`:

```
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1c6d783a54fcc0673ed1f8c5e8650b1d8977ca3e856a03fba0090198e0f16f6d"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="2cdaf0ff92d0829b510edd883a4ac8322c02f2fc1beae95d048b6716076bc014"|' oracle-java9-installer.*
```

Next:

```
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR=9|JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR=9.0.1|' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=181|JAVA_VERSION_MINOR=11|' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk-9|J_DIR=jdk-9.0.1|' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|FILENAME=jdk-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}+${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}_linux-${dld}_bin.tar.gz|FILENAME=jdk-${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}_linux-${dld}_bin.tar.gz|' oracle-java9-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.java.net/java/jdk${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}/archive/${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}/binaries/$FILENAME|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR}+${JAVA_VERSION_MINOR}/$FILENAME|' oracle-java9-installer.*
```

Then install, again:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

You can also download the java9 tgz package separately and place it in `/var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer` once you have tried (and failed) installing (it will make the directory). After performing the above fixes it will install from the cached version (keep a backup copy) instead of trying to download again.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me on 2017-10-18. java 9.0.1

Thank you!

Comment: worked, but this solution will be temporal until PPA maintainer updates the files permanently and applies the new version schema

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me after many headaches trying to get it installed.

Comment: PPA works out of the box for now... Until something changes :-)

Comment: Still facing 
"dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1"
error