# webupd8 oracle-java-9-installer failing with 404

Tags: apt, jdk

When I was installing java jdk using `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

I was getting the error 404 the file was not found after I followed the solution given in

[Can't install Oracle JDK 9](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938314/cant-install-oracle-jdk-9)
which is to change all files oracle-java9-installer.* change version numbers  and SHA256SUM_TGZ as below

```
177-> 178

arm32: c24e8a5ce4dcf77d6e01362ae2d0a57997bb5018da1d74b6934e050d9d3515c7

arm64: 9839c453b7321e491ee752f2e612ca570caaffcf84cf07bf3776f388bb1ecdba
```

the installation fails in post installation :

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-9+178_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java9-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: for now i disabled the checksum error and the installation went through. considering i just started using ubuntu .. I want to learn the correct approach. Thanks for all the responses

Comment: Please clarify the order of events. You installed build-essential (why?), you got a 404 error, you used the Ask Ubuntu answer to edit the sha256sum, then you got the error last mentioned, right?

Comment: I needed build-essential for opencv installation; and yes after the edit appraently the check sum function in post intallation throw the error

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in this problem almost 1 week.

```
 sudo apt-get purge oracle-java9-installer
```

solved my issue. 
Later I also changed Ubuntu Software center server to "Main Server".